# Programmatically post remote form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my rails app I have the following remote form:

```
 <%= form_for :domain_event, 
   url: admin_domain_domain_events_url(@domain.id), 
   method: :post, remote: true,
   html: {id: 'new_domain_event'} do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_area 'descricao', {id: 'event_description', rows:  2, cols: 40} %><br/>
   <%= f.submit 'Registrar', :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
 <%- end -%>
```

It works fine.

I want to programmatically post this form from another point in my code, so I did this:

```
  $('#event_description').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13 && e.ctrlKey) {
      $('#new_domain_event')[0].submit()
        }}
  )
```

Basically it will handle the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> in the textArea and post the form.

The post is happening fine but the behaviour is different from the behaviour when the post button is clicked. When I <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> in the TextArea it posts and then shows the result in the browser instead of calling the ajax callbacks properly.

What would be the correct way to do that post programmatically?

Comment: please elaborate more .......................

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#new_domain_event').submit()
```

without [0]. it works fine for me.

Or:

```
$('#new_domain_event').trigger('submit.rails')
```

[jquery-rails](https://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js#L326)